# How can I add another widget area to the twenty ten wordpress child theme?

Tags: wordpress, themes, widget

I'm trying to create a four column twenty ten child theme.

I have a rough idea how to make three but I don't want to go messing with the original twenty theme to make four.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, you must register another Widget area with a code like this in functions.php:

```
    register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Your Widget Area', 'your_child_theme' ),
    'id' => 'my-widget-area',
    'description' => __( 'The primary widget area', 'your_child_theme' ),
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</li>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
```

then in the code of your child theme, you can use it

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'my-widget-areaa' )) {
  dynamic_sidebar( 'my-widget-area' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks keatch, sorry for being a bit of a dummy but... do I copy all the pages like index, page, single from twenty ten place them in to the child theme and register the extra sidebar/s there?

Comment: See http://aaron.jorb.in/blog/2010/04/introducing-thirty-ten/ for a quick introduction to child themes. For maintenance is better to follow is guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at 
[Twenty Ten Weaver | Wordpress Weaver.](http://wpweaver.info/themes/twenty-ten-weaver/) It's a child theme of Twenty Ten, and features four columns, among other options. Good place to see the code ad theory of Twenty Ten and child themes in action.